# CoreOS: why still get reboot message after turning reboot strategy to off?

Tags: coreos

I still get this.

```
$ vagrant ssh

...

CoreOS stable (681.2.0)

Broadcast message from locksmithd at 2015-07-23 23:41:12.013908559 +0000 Local 
System reboot in 5 minutes!
```

But I already set it off.

```
$ cat user-data.in
#cloud-config
---
coreos:
  update:
    reboot-strategy: off
```

Also inside,

```
$ cat /etc/coreos/update.conf
GROUP=stable
REBOOT_STRATEGY=off
```

So why it still reboots?
Any other place to turn it off?
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Same problem here. Let me know if you have a fix for this.